# Contract states wage is a fixed sum plus respective statutory value added tax

Tags: salary, taxes

What does it mean if a company in Spain agrees to pay a freelancer based in the UK “a monthly fee of 1000 euros plus the respective statutory value added tax” ? Can the company be charged VAT as well for the freelancer services?

Comment: Ask your lawyer. Or at the very, very least please tell us which jurisdiction all parties involved in the contract are in.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I hope that helps

Comment: It helps, but particularly now the UK has left the EU the answer is even more "talk to a lawyer".

Comment: @PhilipKendall would talking to HMRC help?

Comment: HMRC are not your tax advisors.

Comment: @PhilipKendall This looks more like an Accountancy question than a lawerly one to me.

Comment: Welcome to the workplace Gabi23. I've cast a binding close vote here since this is not the type of question we can cover. Details of international handling of VAT and freelance contracts are very specialised domains requiring expert advice that this site doesn't cover. Please check the [tour] and [help/on-topic] to learn more about the sort of questions we can handle here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means they will pay 1,000 Euros a month plus VAT on top if

1. You are registered for VAT and
2. The supply of goods is taxable

@motosubatsu has a good answer but basically if you are going to work professionally cross borders you need an appropriately qualified accountant to advise you on this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're carrying out the work in the UK and the customer is a VAT-registered business located in Spain then unless one of the [special rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vat-how-to-work-out-your-place-of-supply-of-services#special-rules) applies then the "place of supply" is considered to be where the customer belongs i.e. Spain. So you wouldn't pay UK VAT on that.

It's a very good idea to document this fact - assuming they are VAT registered themselves they should be able to supply you with an EU VAT number. Keep that number documented with your records of the work. If they *aren't* VAT-registered (either their turnover is below the threshold or they're a charity etc) then it's a bit different - it may well be treated as  a B2C supply and then it would be subject to UK VAT

In the B2B scenario there *might* be Spanish "VAT" (Impuesto sobre el Valor Anadidio) due, HMRC are unlikely to be any help with that question, and I believe the *customer* will be [liable to pay the VAT](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/default/files/brexit_files/vat-services_en.pdf) to their local state in that case.

You would however be well advised to discuss this arrangement with your accountant/tax advisor, which is good practice regardless but Brexit has made the whole situation way more complicated than it used to be!